# Why do numbers appear at the end of my multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginner at programming and looking for some help with multidimensional arrays (thank you in advance for your help!)  I'm trying to complete a `Kata` on `Code Wars`, specifically "xD-Arrays for dummies."  The prompt wants the user to return a multidimensional array based on an unknown set of arguments.

For example, the `function dim( 3,3,"x" )`, should return, `[['x','x','x'],['x','x','x'],['x','x','x']]`.  First, creating a single array with 3 'x' (i.e. `[x, x, x]`), and then 3 more arrays to store the first array (i.e. `[[x, x, x], [x, x, x], [x, x, x]]`).  To pass the `kata` you will be passed an unknown amount of arguments.

I've tried creating an iterative function, and settled on recursion, since we don't know the amount of arguments we might receive.

This is my code thus far...

```
function dim() {
  // Create an array from the arguments given when the function is called
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  // Store the first element as value
  var val = args.pop();
  // Store the second element which we will repeat for our first array
  var d1 = args.pop();
  var xDarr = [];   

  for (var x = 0; x < d1; x++) {
    if (typeof val == 'function') {
      xDarr.push(val());
    } else {
      xDarr.push(val);
    };
  };

  if (args.length >= 1) {
    var reversedArg = args.reverse();
    return getMatrix(reversedArg, xDarr);
  } else {

    // if we are only passed 2 arguments, such as (dim (2, true)), return xDarr
    return xDarr;
  };
};

function getMatrix(arr, item) {
  // dimArr equals the first array we have created, example: "[x, x, x]"
  var dimArr = item;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // iterate through every other element in our args
    var finalMatrix = [];
    genMatrix(arr[i]);
    dimArr = finalMatrix; 

    // here, the recursion function to return finalMatrix
    function genMatrix(num) {
      if (num === 1) {
        return dimArr;
      } else {
        return finalMatrix.push(dimArr, genMatrix(num - 1))
      };
    };

    console.log("Updated dimArr: " + dimArr)
  };

  return dimArr;
};
```

The function seems to work with arguments that are four elements long, such as `dim( 2,2,2,0 )`, but for odd arguments, such as `dim( 3,3,"x" )`, my function returns `number(s)` at the end of my array.  `dim( 3,3,"x" )` produces the following result: `[ [ 'x', 'x', 'x' ], [ 'x', 'x', 'x' ], [ 'x', 'x', 'x' ], 2 ]`.  I've tried researching using Mozilla but can't figure out what that "2" at the end is.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code in a debugger?

Comment: @Sylwester - thank you for your comment.  I'm still new to Javascript - is their a tool you could recommend or a process?

Answer (score 0):

The number is inserted by the recursive call in the function `getMatrix`:

```
return finalMatrix.push(dimArr, genMatrix(num - 1))
```

The return value here is what `push` returns, and `push` returns the new length of the `finalMatrix` array. This means that if the *recursive* call also gets to execute this line, you actually pass a number as second argument to `push`. And `push` will push whatever arguments you pass to it, hence the number that is pushed here.

You can solve this in different ways, but since the initial call of `genMatrix` doesn't actually use the returned value, you could just avoid returning anything, and just perform the recursion and `push` separately:

```
function genMatrix(num) {
  if (num) {
    finalMatrix.push(dimArr);
    genMatrix(num - 1);
  };
};
```

Note that there are simpler ways to generate a matrix. You could omit this function all together and in `getMatrix` do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  dimArr = Array(arr[i]).fill(dimArr);
}
```

Comment: this makes sense - thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The function should only pass three parameters no more -- no less:

```
function genTable(rows, cells, content) {...
```

**rows:** Number of rows

**cells:** Number of cells per row (also can be considered as columns)

**content:** A value to be placed at every cell

It takes two `for` loops to generate a 2D array (aka table and matrix)

- An empty array is declared which represents the table -- the outer array that contains all of the sub-arrays.

  > |🡄   **table array**   🡆|
  >   **[**  [...], [...], [...], [...]  **]**
- The outer loop creates an empty array which represents a row -- the sub-arrays within the outer array (table)

  > [  **[**...**]**, **[**...**]**, **[**...**]**, **[**...**]**  ]
  >      **row** **row** **row** **row**
- The inner loop pushes the **content** [*3<sup>rd</sup> parameter*] into the array.

  > [  [**content**, **content**, **content**],
  >   [**content**, **content**, **content**], [**content**, **content**, **content**],  [**content**, **content**, **content**]  ]
- Once inner loop iterates **N<sub>c</sub>** times (**N<sub>c</sub>** = **cells** [*2<sup>nd</sup> parameter*]) the next loop of the outer loop pushes the full array into the table array then creates the next array (row).
- This process is repeated **N<sub>r</sub>** times (**N<sub>r</sub>** = **rows** [*1<sup>st</sup> parameter*])
- Once the outer loop is complete the table array is returned.

```js
function genTable(rows, columns, content) {
  const table = [];
  for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    let rowArray = [];
    for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      rowArray.push(content);
    }
    table.push(rowArray);
  }
  return table;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(genTable(4, 6, 'X')));

console.log(JSON.stringify(genTable(8, 2, 'Y')));

console.log(JSON.stringify(genTable(2, 10, 'Z')));
```